# CardView: Setting background color removes the rounded edges

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a cardview with rounded corners:

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/chronology_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">   <------- corner radius set in the layout.
```

view is showing with rounded corners. -> ok.

When setting the backgroundcolor by code ...

```
holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(getBackgroundColor());
```

... then the rounded corners are gone. It lookes like a rectangle with the correct new color.

How to set the backgroundcolor at runtime and keeping the corners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to add this to your activity code:

```
CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.chronology_card);
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#put here the HEX code for the color"));
```

I tried it before and worked fine without any problems in corners radius.

Answer (score 3):

The `CardView` manages its own background drawable with rounded corners.
Using `setBackgroundColor` you are overriding this background.

You should use the method **`setCardBackgroundColor`** instead of `setBackgroundColor`.